# Send Payment to Customers in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

This is my Scenario:
I want to build a CtoC application, which is for Customer-to-Customers(seller and buyer).
Like Amazon Marketplace, Ali Express, Udemy.
Sellers will post their products and Buyers will purchase any products on this site.
So that, 95% of payment will be pay to Seller, 5% will be pay to the site Admin.
To create the payment to Sellers, how should I use the Stripe API?
Sellers will register their Card info in the site DB.

Comment: you'd probably want to go through the guides here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you share the APIs to manage them? I have to use the apis.

Comment: if you go into a specific guide, it gives you specific examples that use the Stripe API

Comment: Could you share the guide?